# Wrong shortcuts-keys in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

#### Description:

I have some keyboard shortcuts-keys that do not behave the correct way in some programs.
For example in [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: it should open the "export image" window to save the image.
Or, when I want to take a screenshot of the active windows, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prnt Screen</kbd> combination is taking a screenshot of the Unity search bar (which wasn't open at all at that time.).

#### Question:

Why are these shortcuts wrong and how to get them back properly?
I don't want to search for and list more examples here, but I am pretty sure I will encountered some others in the future.

**Details:**
I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04: `4.15.0-42-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux` with Unity: `7.5.0`.

#### Update:

`xev` outputs:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30578572, (104,-9), root:(2255,237),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30578780, (104,-9), root:(2255,237),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30407692, (736,229), root:(2887,475),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30407820, (736,229), root:(2887,475),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

<kbd>E</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30496732, (156,-13), root:(2307,233),
    state 0x10, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30496796, (156,-13), root:(2307,233),
    state 0x10, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30703253, (157,-18), root:(2308,228),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30704005, (157,-18), root:(2308,228),
    state 0x11, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    atom 0x14b (_NET_WM_STATE), time 30704789, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    atom 0x14b (_NET_WM_STATE), time 30704789, state PropertyNewValue
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30805069, (237,-20), root:(2388,226),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x199, subw 0x0, time 30805157, (237,-20), root:(2388,226),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear
```

Comment: Do you use a bluetooth keyboard? Are only shortcuts affected that contain the Alt key? For troubleshooting, please open a terminal and run `xev`. First, press `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `e` individually and look at the symbols that are produced by the keys. Then, press them altogether (like a shortcut). Do they produce the same symbols? Is the order of press/release events correct (i.e. `e` pressed _before_ `Alt` released)?

Comment: No, wire keyboard from a dock station. Or native laptop keyboard (same behaviour). The Ctrl and E keys seem correctly detected. The Shift and Alt keys give me a different output using xev. I'll update the main post to add details.

Comment: Have you run the gnome-control-center (aka "Settings") program and looked there (under "Devices" > "Keyboard") for conflicting keyboard shortcuts? There might be something already there linked to `Ctrl-Alt-e` for example.

Comment: There is no conflicts with the original gnome settings.